# Add i2s Audio in device tree for SAM9x60 board

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, alsa, device-tree

Our team has a SAM9x60 board and recently add an external audio board (UDA1334A, link: [Documents](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-i2s-stereo-decoder-uda1334a.pdf)). Unfortunately, this document has guide for Raspberry Pi only, and somehow it's really different with our board device tree. So I have tried myself to add into device tree, mostly based on SAM9x60's [Tutorial](https://www.linux4sam.org/bin/view/Linux4SAM/UsingI2SC) with another board, but it's really different.

As I understand, the audio board use UDA1334 codec, and I have to add a sound tag to device tree, like SAM9x60 tutorial:

```
sound {
        compatible = "mikroe,mikroe-proto";
        model = "wm8731 @ sam9x60ek";
        i2s-controller = <&i2s>;
        audio-codec = <&wm8731>;
        dai-format = "i2s";
        };
```

But I haven't found any driver for this card. After look around, I tried with simple-audio-card

```
sound {
        compatible = "simple-audio-card";
        simple-audio-card,name = "1334 Card";
        simple-audio-card,format = "i2s";
        simple-audio-card,widgets = "Speaker", "Speakers";
        simple-audio-card,routing = "Speakers", "Speaker";
        simple-audio-card,bitclock-master = <&codec_dai>;
        simple-audio-card,frame-master = <&codec_dai>;
        simple-audio-card,cpu {
            #sound-dai-cells = <0>;
                sound-dai = <&i2s>;
            };
        codec_dai: simple-audio-card,codec {
            #sound-dai-cells = <1>;
            sound-dai = <&uda1334>;
        };
    };

        uda1334: codec@1a {
            compatible = "nxp,uda1334";
            nxp,mute-gpios = <&pioA 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
            nxp,deemph-gpios = <&pioC 3 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
            status = "okay";
        };
```

When booting, I received message:

```
OF: /sound/simple-audio-card,codec: could not get #sound-dai-cells for /codec@1a
asoc-simple-card sound: parse error -22                                         
asoc-simple-card: probe of sound failed with error -22
```

So have I do the right way with `simple-audio-card`? Or any other way? In normal, ALSA recorded a classD sound card, but I think it is just a amplifier. Sorry because I'm an Android SW Developer and have to do the HW job from a quit people.

External Question: I have investigate on Raspberry device tree based on UDA1334 document, it's so different, as I understand, Rasp use HiFiberry Dac already, but how could it work with an external DAC like UDA1334? No external node in device tree I've seen? Look like they just open `dtoverlay=hifiberry-dac`, `dtoverlay=i2s-mmap` and it work.

Comment: "*But I haven't found any driver for this card*" -- Apparently you did not search very hard: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/sound/soc/codecs/uda1334.c and https://www.kernelconfig.io/config_snd_soc_uda1334 and https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/sound/uda1334.txt

Comment: Hi @sawdust, I know this one, but I thought it's codec driver. As you can see, I already add codec in device tree. As I understand, I have to found driver for this board like `mikroe,mikroe-proto` in their example.
Today ALSA has loaded my card, but instead of `uda1334` codec, I use `spdif-transmitter` codec. Better but no sound at the moment. Actually does board use this `nxp,uda1334` codec? I'm not even sure about it?